# How do I pass a parameter into a JS function without wrap it in an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

For a long time I had this question: how do I pass a parameter to a JS function without wrap it in a anonymous function?

Let's see an example:

```
var
x = 10,
foo = function( num ) {
    console.log("Number: " + num);
};

// This way works, but I wouldn't like to wrap it in an anonymous function
setTimeout(function() {
    foo( x );
}, 1000 );

// Is there a way to pass the 'x' parameter here?
setTimeout( foo, 2000 );
```

Is there a way to pass a parameter on the second setTimeout call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern Javascript engines (MDN also has a [shim that makes this work in IE9 and older](http://Callback_arguments)):

```
setTimeout( foo, 2000, x );
```

or use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill), which is not quite as modern, but still modern enough to have no support in IE8 (again there is a [shim on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill)):

```
setTimeout( foo.bind( null, x ), 2000 );
```

Replace `null` with whatever you want `this` to be in your function if you normally would call that function with a context. In your above example, `null` works well.